# Flutter workmanager not work when app is terminated [2022]

Tags: flutter

I'm trying in Android to show a local notification as a test, everything works fine if the app is foreground and background, but I need the notification to show when the app is terminated, which is this mode (when I terminate the app) workmanager doesn't work .

I have seen many questions and answers but I have not found anything clear, does anyone know how to make the notification appear when the application is finished? I don't want to use push notifications or Fcm, I know that, but I need to know how to do this locally.

my main.dart
I'm trying to show a local notification as a test, everything works fine if the app is foreground and background, but I need the notification to show when the app is terminated, which is this mode (when I terminate the app) workmanager doesn't work .

I have seen many questions and answers but I have not found anything clear, does anyone know how to make the notification appear when the application is finished? I don't want to use push notifications or Fmc, I know that, but I need to know how to do this locally.

my main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:workmanager/workmanager.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

void callbackDispatcher() {

  Workmanager.executeTask((task, inputData) async {
    if (task == 'uniqueKey') {
      ///do the task in Backend for how and when to send notification

      final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
      const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
      AndroidNotificationDetails('your channel id', 'your channel name',
          'your channel description',
          importance: Importance.max,
          priority: Priority.high,
          showWhen: false);
      const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
      NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          0,
          'hello',
          '1245',
          platformChannelSpecifics,
          payload: 'item x');
    }
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  Workmanager.initialize(
      callbackDispatcher,
      isInDebugMode:
      true);

  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
  AndroidInitializationSettings(
      '@mipmap/ic_launcher');
  final IOSInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS =
  IOSInitializationSettings();
  final MacOSInitializationSettings initializationSettingsMacOS =
  MacOSInitializationSettings();
  final InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
      macOS: initializationSettingsMacOS);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
      onSelectNotification: selectNotification);

  runApp(const MyApp());
}


Future selectNotification(String payload) async {
  if (payload != null) {
    debugPrint('notification payload: $payload');
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text("Work manager Example"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Workmanager.registerPeriodicTask(
                    "1",
                    "uniqueKey",
                    frequency: Duration(minutes: 15),
                    initialDelay: Duration(seconds:10),
                  );
                  print('START');
                },
                child: Text("Run Task")),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Workmanager.cancelByUniqueName("1");
                  print('cancel');
                },
                child: Text("Cancel Task"))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I'm facing with the same issue, have you solved this one?

Comment: @Aurora I've still been investigating and nothing, have you seen anything?

Comment: Hello, my solution was to switch to firebase cloud messaging. Its so much easier and free.  I also wrote medium post on how to,  and if you like you can check it : https://medium.com/@tugbacekirge/firebase-cloud-messaging-with-flutter-b103435a3b2e

Comment: Please help, Im also facing the same problem.

Comment: Can you try listening for app termination and then running workmanager again